# how to convert merge query into hive insert operation by using subquery or CTE?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, insert, impala

> i have this merge statement, but I don't want use this merge
> statement in hive and impala, is any other way to create same logic by
> using insert and using any type of subquery and CTE.

```
MERGE INTO member_staging AS x
    USING (SELECT member_id, first_name, last_name, rank FROM members) y
    ON (x.member_id  = y.member_id)
    WHEN MATCHED AND (
        x.first_name <> y.first_name OR 
        x.last_name <> y.last_name OR 
        x.rank <> y.rank
    )
    THEN
        UPDATE SET x.first_name = y.first_name, 
                   x.last_name  = y.last_name, 
                   x.rank       = y.rank
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES (y.member_id, y.first_name, y.last_name, y.rank);
```

Comment: Why don’t you want to use a MERGE statement. As a merge does both INSERT and UPDATE you’d have to write 2 separate statements to achieve the same outcome as the merge

Comment: for merge table should in ORC and table should be in bucket right. This is sample code only. our requirement like this only, even breaking the statement is okay for me. but i need as insert operation.

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea what any of your last comment meant

Comment: is any way to convert same logic using insert and subqueries?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to update records using an insert statement? If so then the answer is no

Answer (score 0):

You can use **update** and **insert** like this

```
-- Update existing records
UPDATE member_staging
SET first_name = y.first_name,
    last_name = y.last_name,
    rank = y.rank
FROM member_staging x
JOIN members y ON x.member_id = y.member_id
WHERE x.first_name <> y.first_name
    OR x.last_name <> y.last_name
    OR x.rank <> y.rank;

-- Insert new records
INSERT INTO TABLE member_staging
SELECT y.member_id, y.first_name, y.last_name, y.rank
FROM members y
LEFT JOIN member_staging x ON x.member_id = y.member_id
WHERE x.member_id IS NULL;
```